# batch file with xcopy works from cmd line and not from simple c# winform app

Tags: c#, batch-file, xcopy

I have a pretty basic batch file, boiled it down to just this xcopy. It never copies the files. If I run the xcopy command from the cmd line, it works.

Here is the xcopy line:

```
xcopy /Y "\\01iisdv130\Myapp\Log\%1\*.txt" "c:\LogFilesParser\Files\App\%1\"*
```

The %1 is a date, like 20190401. I used `ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")` to run the batch file. The directories already exist and I checked the permissions on my local c:-drive for that directory. I get no error, but the files don't get copied. There is only two or three files, but I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: For your information: as I believe the problem being in the C#-code instead of the `xcopy` command, I've decided to add the `C#` tag.

Comment: I believe you aht to double the %-signs in a batch file; otherwise `%1` becomes expanded to its first command line argument...

Comment: I don't see any reason for the trailing asterisk and/or the whitespace which follows it!

Comment: I removed the asterisk at the end, but it did not help.

Comment: If I double the % sign, I get instead xcopy /Y \\01iisdv130\Myapp\Log\%1\*.txt c:\LogFilesParser\Files\App\%1\

Comment: `"cmd.exe"` doesn't run a batch file, it runs `cmd.exe`, so how exactly are you invoking the batch file? If you're using `%1`, how are you passing the date as that argument to the batch file too?

Comment: ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe"); I set the arguments in startInfo.Arguments.

Comment: So you felt your `C#` code was irrelevant to the question?

Comment: There wasn't a whole lot in the C# code. Just picking up the date to be used and the ProcessStartInfo instance.